# Is there a way I can add widgets to my list in flutter after a .toList() call?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add another item to my list in a flutter app. The problem comes in the `children: quotes.map((quote) => quoteTemplate(quote)).toList()` part. I have tried adding a text widget after it to try and test it. However, I constantly get error. The error says I cannot add list to Widgets. My full code is.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "quote.dart";

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: QuoteList(),
));

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteListState createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {
  int index = 1;
  List <Quote> quotes = [
    Quote(text: "1. It always seems impossible until it's done.", author: "Nelson Mandela", date: "1954"),
    Quote(text: "2. Don't watch the clock; do what it does. Keep going.", author: "Sam Levenson", date: "1985"),
    Quote(text: "3. Live life to the fullest, and focus on the positive.", author: "Matt Cameron", date: "1965"),
  ]; 
  
  Widget quoteTemplate(quote) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0),
      elevation: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              quote.text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 17.0),
            Text(
              quote.author,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11.0,
                color: Colors.grey[700],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 17.0),
            Text(
              quote.date,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11.0,
                color: Colors.grey[750],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Quote App",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:
        Center(
          child: Column(
            children: quotes.map((quote) => quoteTemplate(quote)).toList(),
                
            //quotes.map((quote) => quoteTemplate(quote)).toList().toString(),
          ),
        ),       
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to an existing list using the `...` syntax:

```dart
Column(
            children: [
               ...quotes.map((quote) => quoteTemplate(quote)).toList(),
                Text(),
                Text(),
           ],     
 ),
```

Comment: But does the `...` append to the column list or the children list?

Comment: It appends to the list of children. You can see you initialise a list in the column with [ ]. You add your quotes to that list and the other widgets as well